# How to dynamically create a folder in s3 when doing cloudformation package

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline where I am using cloudformation package to package the deployment . Now I want cloudformation to upload the artifacts inside a dynamically created folder with current datetimestamp. Is there any way I can do that? My solution is given below which doesn't work.

build.sh

```
other commands
timestamp=$(date +%s)
aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file packaged-template.yaml --s3-bucket bucket name --s3-prefix cfn-deployment/$timestamp
```

Now I want use this `timestamp` variable inside `deploy.sh` shell script where cloudformation deploy command I am using

Comment: Than you say "cloudformation to upload" do you mean the cli command aws cloudforamtion package? And than you say it does work do you get any kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "folders" or directories in Amazon S3. It's an Object Storage. The "paths" are effectively just the object name. The paths have forward slashes in their name and the Amazon S3 Console will treat that in a special way to make it look like you have directories. In reality, you don't.

What you're trying to do does not make sense and it's not possible. Whenever you need to upload your artifacts to S3, just specify the path and it will work out, no need to do anything through CloudFormation.

#### Example

Creating an empty bucket

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $MY_BUCKET --region us-east-1
```

Uploading a file with key containing today's date:

```
echo 'hello' > myfile
aws s3 cp myfile s3://$MY_BUCKET/$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d")/myfile
upload: ./myfile to s3://REDACTED/2023-01-09/myfile
```

Listing the objects through `s3 ls` (making it look like your linux list):

```
 aws s3 ls s3://$MY_BUCKET
                           PRE 2023-01-09/
```

Listing the objects through the API (`s3api list-objects-v2`):

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $MY_BUCKET
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "2023-01-09/myfile",
            "LastModified": "2023-01-09T10:43:20.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184\"",
            "Size": 6,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ]
}
```